# stack divs but have them wrap with a fixed height

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling

I have a list of DIVs, that are stacked on top of each other.  Basically they are not floating.

The height is fixed to 500px, and once the DIVs get to the bottom, I would like them to then start in the next column.  So with about 200 items, you would just scroll horizontally to see the divs instead of vertically.

The number of DIVs can be very large, and ideally i would like the rows to get pushed when the screen is re-sized.  So not having a fixed row, that float next to each other.

```
<div class="row show-grid">
    <div class="span1 span1-nofloat">Item 1</div>
    <div class="span1 span1-nofloat">Item 1</div>
    <div class="span1 span1-nofloat">Item 1</div>
    <div class="span1 span1-nofloat">Item 1</div>
</div>

.span1 {
width: 60px;
}

.span1-nofloat {
    float: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: So, to make sure I am understanding you correctly.  Assuming you had say 200 divs.  You want two columns that are 100 divs tall with the left column containing div 1-100 and right column containing divs 101-200?  Or the opposite which would be 2 rows with 100 divs wide, the top row divs 1-100 and bottom row divs 101-200?

Comment: If you're displaying tabular data, why not simply use a table?  This seems to be one of the few times where a table is the right call.

Comment: if 200 Divs, I would most likely have about 20 columns depending on the height of the screen. because ones the stack hits the bottom, it should start a new row.  I can't use table, because there is multiple views.

Comment: impossible with just CSS (at least I think so), but not too troublesome with JavaScript. can you use JavaScript?

Comment: I was hoping for a CSS solution, but if JS is the only way, yes, I can use it.

Comment: @GarethCornish Nothing is impossible! :) (Well, some things are, but not this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the HTML. All I did was add an ID to the container, so I could get a reference to it easily:

```
<div class="row show-grid" id="gridcontainer">
    <div class="span1 span1-nofloat">Item 1</div>
    <div class="span1 span1-nofloat">Item 1</div>
    ....
    <div class="span1 span1-nofloat">Item 1</div>
    <div class="span1 span1-nofloat">Item 1</div>
</div>
```

Then the CSS. I set the `.span1` class with a border and spacing just to make it easier to see:

```
.span1 {
    width: 60px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 20px;
}

.span1-nofloat {
    float: none;
}

.show-grid{
    max-height: 220px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.show-column{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Finally, the javascript. Run this from your onload event, or directly after the HTML has been loaded. I just threw this together, so it can probably be improved a lot:

```
var maxheight = 200;
var container = document.getElementById('gridcontainer');
var columns = [document.createElement('div')];
columns[0].className = 'show-column';
var currentcolumn = columns[0];
var currentheight = 0;
var count = container.childNodes.length;
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
    var child = container.childNodes[0];
    var height = child.offsetHeight | 0;
    if(currentheight + height > maxheight){
        currentcolumn = document.createElement('div');
        currentcolumn.className = 'show-column';
        columns.push(currentcolumn);
        currentheight = 0;
    }
    currentcolumn.appendChild(child);
    currentheight += height;
}
container.innerHTML = '';
for(var j=0;j<columns.length;j++){
     container.appendChild(columns[j]);   
}
```

The `maxheight` variable is the maximum height of the container, and set to 20px less in the JavaScript than the CSS, so the container has space for the horizontal scroll bar.

A JSFiddle of the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/djBK3/

Comment: Could this still work in a responsive design, so it adjusted based on the resizing of the browser screen, instead of having it a fixed height?

Comment: You could calculate the maxheight variable instead of setting it, if you want. To make it properly responsive, you'd need a slightly different function for the onresize event as well. This jsFiddle works for FireFox - you may need to work it a bit to make it IE compatible: http://jsfiddle.net/djBK3/2/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using CSS3 transforms: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/yk566/)

The idea is that you start out with normal "floated boxes", as if they're stacking horizontally, but then the container is transformed with `rotate(-90deg)`, so that the boxes are stacked vertically. To correct the box content orientation which is now incorrect, those are transformed back with `rotate(90deg)`.

Thus the width of the box container actually defines it's eventual height.
Try adding or subtracting box items and you'll notice that the boxes are stacked vertically from left to right :)

Comment: This works great if the boxes are square, but not so much if they're not, and especially not if they have variable heights.

Answer (score 1):

How about using CSS3 columns to achieve a flowing column layout using CSS? It's what CSS columns were designed for, after all. The trick to using elements that are normally block-level inside a column layout for this kind of effect is to apply `display: inline-block` to the inner elements. Something like this will fill in a div top-to-bottom, left-to-right with smaller divs of a fixed width.

The CSS:

```
.columns div {
    width: 60px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.columns {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    height: 242px;
    -moz-column-width: 65px;
    -webkit-column-width: 65px;
    column-width: 65px;
    -moz-column-gap: 0;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
    column-gap: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="columns">
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
    <div>Item</div>
</div>
```

If your divs are all the same height and you want a consistent bottom margin, the dimensions can be a little fiddly, but you can figure it out for your particular situation in a couple of minutes with a calculator by adding up the box size of each element. If your boxes will vary by height, just make sure none of them are as tall as or taller than the containing element or its content will wrap around to the next column; this is really the correct behavior (you don't want to hide your content, right?) but it is a little unsightly.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WGScP/4/) that demonstrates the idea.